# Can R Create a plot like this?

Tags: r, ggplot2

The plot below (taken from a e-text book on statistics) shows some hypothetical data for TV advertising dollars and associated sales. A line is fitted for the data and then the error of each data point is shown. Is there a pre-created plot like this that exists either using the native plot() function or ggplot2?

[image]

Comment: See [this answer on CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/228587/3162) for R code showing how to do this in `ggplot2`.

Comment: Looks like it was created in R...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In base R

```
## Example data
x = runif(50, 0,300)
y = 5 + x/20 + rnorm(50,0,3)

plot(x,y, pch=20, col="red")
LM = lm(y ~x)
abline(LM)
segments(x, LM$fitted.values, x, y)
```

[image: Fitted line]